# PyCharm not highlighting syntax error from third party libs

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm doesn't seem to be highlighting syntax errors from the `logging` module

[image]

Would anyone know what setting I could be missing to have caused this?

**EDIT**

I presume this should be classified as an `Unresolved reference`, for which I've upgraded to be `Error` under `Inspections`, yet it is still not being highlighted.

Comment: Maybe file indices are invalid, try [cleaning up the system cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html)..

Comment: @Jezor Cleared cache and restarted, but not helping

Comment: if it is not limited to third party libraries check your power saver mode status, inspection and Highlighting levels.

Comment: @ڪڌݳݳيةѵيةทﻹݪݫ It is in `Inspection` mode

Comment: It's a bug, I created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20071

Comment: @user2235698 Thank you